Can I apply to internships at large US tech companies as a student with previous full time experience?
I'm going back to school for an MS degree in the US. I have previously obtained an MS degree and worked for 5 years as a software engineer full-time.
To both finance my studies and gain experience in the area I plan to specialize in during my MS I would like to apply to internships as soon as possible. Now, this is obviously company-dependent (or is it?) but say I apply to the usual suspects, i.e. Amazon, Microsoft. Google, Meta, will my previous work experience disqualify me from internship positions? Job ads don't seem to touch on this point.

Going through the same situation ! Having 8 years of work exp. But in my case I am feeling like I am forgetting every work related stuff. Best wishes

Many people go back to studying after working.
So, most companies accept interns based on the course they are enrolled on at the time and don't refuse them based on a previous work history.
I did exactly that and went to an "internship" for a multi-national company, no issues.

Very encouraging, thank you :). I knew this was the case for PhD students but I wasn't sure about MS students.

@Peter My experience was for my DUT (linked with a B.Eng Hons).

If you were serving time in jail, with no software engineering experience, you could apply for a work from home (in this case, jail) at the companies you mentioned.  Such a person is unlikely to be hired for a variety of reasons.
In your own case it, all depends on many factors, such as the company, their needs at the time, your own ability to sell yourself, and even the person making the decision.  So, apply and do not take initial rejections as a definitive answer.  You can always apply again.
Something you did not address is what is more important to you:  financing your studies or gaining experience?  If the former there may be more lucrative and flexible earning opportunities.  For example, after hours babysitting pays surprisingly well, allows time for study, and does not interfere with one's class schedule.
